# Indefinite integral with partial fractions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$\int{ -5x^3-2x^2+32\over x^4-4x^3 } dx $$

How should I solve this indefinite integral using partial fractions?
I have already checked the online calculators but the answer they give me is incorrect whenever I check it.

I have used partial fractions of type ${A\over x}+{B\over x^2} + {C\over x^3} + {D\over (x-4)}.$

The answer I get when I solve the problem is ${2(x-2) \over x^2 }-5\ln(x-4) + C.$
However, the answer shows as incorrect when I input it.

Comment: What did you get when you tried? Did you use long division to put the denominator in a higher power than the numerator in the second one?

Comment: For the first integral, use $\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2}+\frac{c}{x^3}+\frac{d}{x-4}$; in the second, divide first and then use $\frac{a}{x+1}+\frac{b}{x+3}$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28-5x^3-2x^2%2B32%29%2F%28x^4-4x^3%29) gives $\displaystyle\frac{2(x+2)}{x^2}-5\log(4-x)+C$.

Comment: Could you show your solution so we can see where you went wrong?  For example, what values of $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Using partial fraction decomposition on the integrand, we can write

\begin{equation*}
\int\frac{-5x^3-2x^2+32}{(x-4)x^3}dx=\int (-\frac{8}{x^3}-\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{5}{x-4})dx=\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}-5\int\frac{1}{x-4}dx.
\end{equation*}

Using the substitution $u=x-4,~du=dx$ for the final integral, we get

\begin{equation*}
-5\ln(u)+\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}+C.
\end{equation*}

Finish by substituting back for $u=x-4$ to get
$$
\int\frac{-5x^3-2x^2+32}{x^4-4x^3}dx=-5\ln(x-4)+\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}+C.~_{\square}
$$